# mysql query: find if at least one number 2 is in a set of fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a lot of integer fields

like:

```
fields1 | fields2 | fields3 | fields4 ....
0       | 1       | 0       | 2       ....
```

there is an easy way to find if at least one number 2 is in this fields

except of the long way of

```
where  fields1 =2 or fields2=2  or fields3 =2 or  fields4 = 2 .........
```

**another question** if there easy way to select the rows that
numbers 2 appear between 2 to 3 times in this fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 2 IN (fields1,fields2,fields3,fields4)
```

Though I should suggest that your normalize your database structure.  This kind of one to many relationship is better represented by using a keys to link up relations between tables.  You could store your id values in one table and then junction them to the relevant integers in another table using their ids, so one row could own multiple integers.

http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 1):

1. `WHERE 2 IN (fields1, fileds2, .... )`
2. This question suggests that your data is not normalized properly.

Answer (score 0):

The following query finds all rows where at least 2 fields have the value 2. Ugly, slow, but works.

```
select *
  from tab
 where 2 in(field1, field2, field3, field4)
   and if(field1 = 2,1,0) +
       if(field2 = 2,1,0) + 
       if(field3 = 2,1,0) +
       if(field4 = 2,1,0) >= 2;
```